# Emulator Takes Much Time and at the end it Fail

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am new to developing Android applications. My first application takes too much time to load, and fails at the end.

I'm using a Windows 8 laptop with 4GB of RAM and an Intel processor. I'm writing all of this because I saw an answer regarding Windows.

```
[2014-03-08 07:26:52 - Mytest] Android Launch! [2014-03-08 07:26:52 -
Mytest] adb is running normally.
[2014-03-08 07:26:52 - Mytest] Performing
com.example.mytest.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-03-08 07:26:53 - Mytest] Automatic Target Mode: launching new
emulator with compatible AVD 'nnt'
[2014-03-08 07:26:53 - Mytest] Launching a new emulator with Virtual
Device 'nnt'
[2014-03-08 07:27:15 - Mytest] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-03-08 07:27:15 - Mytest] Waiting for HOME
('android.process.acore') to be launched
[2014-03-08 07:39:36 - Mytest] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-03-08 07:39:36 - Mytest] Uploading Mytest.apk onto device
'emulator-5554'
[2014-03-08 07:39:36 - Mytest] Installing Mytest.apk...
[2014-03-08 07:41:51 - Mytest] Failed to install Mytest.apk on device
'emulator-5554!
[2014-03-08 07:41:51 - Mytest] (null) [2014-03-08 07:41:51 - Mytest]
Launch canceled!
```

Please let me know.

Comment: This might be because you're allocating too much RAM. How much do you allocate to your emulator and under how much load is your laptop at that time?

Comment: @user3390805 - Can you provide me a little more details about the EMULATOR. You can find info about it in your AVD. RULE of THUMB => Make sure you select a lower android version like 2 or 3, and try to use lesser RAM space like 0.5GB or lesser.

Comment: Jeroen 1. while creating AVD I give 700 mb Ram. about Laptop load there are only emulator an a firefox opened at the same time. Also I am Norton 360. Suddev 2. Lower android version mean- while creating AMD i've to fix device: lower & Target higher or both lower. Do I've to specify Ram 500 while creating AMD?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before. I have tried following steps.

1. Plug-in your charger, if it's not connected.
2. Start emulator from AVD - manager, this works for most of the time.

Comment: anyone else here who can suggest me best. If you've time then you can help me at skype also.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Genymotion** emulator, it is free for personal use and it works smooth. You also can use Eclipse plug-in.

Get it here: [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)

If you having troubles with installation, here is [User Guide](https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/doc/).

I am using it and I am very happy.